# SSRS Attemp was made to set a report parameter

Tags: ssrs-2012

Error = An attempt was made to set a parameter '@Reload' that is not defined in this report.

NB: I get the same error in VS as when deployed and running in a browser (tested in IE and Chrome).

I have a textbox that has an action to load a report with several parameters.
@Reload is a Boolean in my drill thru report and I set the parameter to false.

What I have seen from other answers to a similar question is your first thing to check is the spelling (case sensitivity) of the parameter and make sure you pass a value that is of the same type, pretty sure I have this correct, Reload can only be spelt one way - false is a boolean! What else can I check?
Is my report corrupt or am I missing the obvious.

NB: My drill thru report has defined the parameter as Hidden, Boolean, Default = true.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I have read every post here in case someone had the same issue so apologies if this is a repeated issue. Anyhow, for the sake of somebody else having the same problem.

I confess I can't avoid my 99th dummies award but here is the solution. I finally figure out the issue is that the parameters setting for an action of "Go to report" parameter names (LHS in Action tab) don't require the @ symbol so in a sense I did fail the spelling check!